# User query in PHP does not work

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, php, query

I would like to get user query in my custom PHP plugin.

According to this document, the code would be like this.
https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/element-queries/user-queries.html#example

```
$queryAllUsers_email = User::find()->email($new_email);
if (count($queryAllUsers_email) > 0) {
    // ...
}
```

`User` means `Craft\Elements\User` class.

However, the count is 0.

It would be grateful for me if you tell me what is wrong.

Comment: Try adding `->all()` after `email($new_email)` as per [the example](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/element-queries/user-queries.html#email)

Comment: I tried, but the result is same.

Comment: Not related to the question, but you can use ".count()" instead of using ".all()" and count() the result. This saves lots of query time.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$queryAllUsers_email = User::find()
    ->email($new_email)
    ->anyStatus()
    ->all();
```

It's likely the email address you're searching for is for a user that isn't activated yet or suspended, etc.

Using [anyStatus](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/element-queries/user-queries.html#parameters) will search for the user regardless of their status.

Comment: Thank you, I tried it. However, the count is still 0 although the e-mail address has already been taken.

Comment: You've verified that `$new_email` is actually set to an email address that exists in the `users` table?

Comment: I think so, `$new_email` is the input of e-mail field in the form.